# How to get a stored procedure as a text and alter it on another server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to get a stored procedure as a text and update its twin(!) on the other server with an excel macro. So I got this stored procedure on the server which has the newest version of the stored procedure:

```
Declare @Lines Table (Line NVARCHAR(MAX));
Declare @FullText NVARCHAR(max) = '';
INSERT @Lines EXEC sp_helptext 'StoredProcName';
Select @FullText = @FullText + Line From @Lines;
Select @FullText
```

@Fulltext has the complete code of 'StoredProcName'. I would like to get this code, cut the first 6 letters (CREATE), append it with "ALTER" and run it on the target server/database to update its twin(!). I got this excel macro to realize it:

```
Sub GetStoredProcedure()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection 
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 
    Dim cmd1 As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
    
    'Getting data from local
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
        "Data Source=myDataSource;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=myDataBase;" & _
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        
    
    cn.Open 'Connection establishment.
    
    cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd1.CommandText = "UpdateStoredProcedure"
    
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Parameter = Cells(i, 1).Value
    cmd1.Parameters.Refresh
    cmd1.Parameters("@sPName").Value = Parameter
    Set rs = cmd1.Execute
    rs.Open
    Debug.Print rs.State
    Range("K2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Next i
    
    
    rs.Close 'Deactivating the recordset.
    cn.Close 'Deactivating the connetion.
    
  
    
End Sub
```

After running this macro I get the Run-time error '3704': Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Remove the `rs.Open` instruction, the recordset you're getting from `cmd1.Execute` should be ready to iterate. Which specific line is failing with that error?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Thanks! I will delete my comment...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I get the error message on line Range("K2").CopyFromRecordset rs but removing that instruction does not change anything.

Comment: Why do this in code that you struggle to write and debug? Use SSMS to generate a script for your procedure in the source database and then run that script in the target database.

Comment: @SMor  We are using some stored procedures in SSRS Reports. Sometimes we update the local stored procedures. My macro gets the last update dates from both servers(local and global). If the global stored procedures has older last-Update date, they will be updated. So this is the main idea. I want to do this with code to save time.

Comment: Don't use `sp_helptext`, instead select from system tables such as `sys.sql_modules` and `sys.procedures`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetStoredProcedure()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd1 As ADODB.Command
    
    'Getting data from local
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
        "Data Source=myDataSource;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=myDataBase;" & _
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        
    cn.Open 'Connection establishment.
    
    Dim sProc As String, sCode As String, n As Long, i As Long
    With Range("K:L")
        .Font.Name = "Lucida Console"
        .Font.Size = 11
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .ColumnWidth = 85
    End With
    
    Set cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd1
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        
        For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            sProc = Cells(i, 1).Value
            .CommandText = "EXEC sp_helptext '" & sProc & "';"
            Set rs = .Execute
            sCode = rs.GetString
            sCode = Replace(sCode, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
            Range("K" & i).Value = sCode
            Range("L" & i).Value = Replace(sCode, "CREATE PROCEDURE", "ALTER PROCEDURE")
            n = n + 1
        Next i
    End With
   
    rs.Close 'Deactivating the recordset.
    cn.Close 'Deactivating the connetion.
    MsgBox n & " procedures", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```